# SkelJS cell height 100% vertical align middle

Tags: css, height, cell, vertical-alignment

Please look at these two examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/GBVF8/5/ (with SkelJS)

http://jsfiddle.net/5Br2N/5/ (without SkelJS)

Here's my css for the SkelJS example:

```
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    border:3px solid black;
}
.container {
    height:100%;
    border:3px solid darkslategray;
}
.row {
    height:100%;
    border:3px solid gray;
}
.col1 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:3px solid green;
    height:100%;
}
.col2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:3px solid red;
    height:100%;
}
```

I would like cell heights like shown in the second example but using SkelJS. Basically I want the first and second columns to be vertically aligned in the middle. I want the height to be fluid so it just centers in the middle based on the content inside the tallest div. I don't want to have to set a static height, like 300px. Please advise. Thanks!